# ¿Qué SOAP debería usar en Laravel 10.x.x?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, soap

Estoy en proceso de actualizar un proyecto de Laravel 5.5 a la versión 10.x.x.

El proyecto original creo que utiliza el paquete: `zendframework/zend-soap`.

En cambio, en el nuevo instalé: [Laminas SOAP](https://packagist.org/packages/laminas/laminas-soap)

1. No sé que cambios debo aplicar, si alguien me puede guiar se lo agradecería mucho.
2. De forma temporal, he modificado el siguiente fichero: C:\proyectos\miProyecto\vendor\laminas\laminas-soap\src\Client.php añadiendo un try/catch y un log de errores en el catch. El error que se registra es el siguiente: `Error: Unknown SOAP client option`
3. Hay un fichero .wsdl y se define un array "classmap" con varias opciones, entiendo que el modo es "wsdl", ¿correcto? [SOAP Client different modes](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-soap/client/)

Comment: La 1 y la 2 son imposibles de responder. La 3 no la entiendo, además nunca he visto un WS SOAP sin su respectivo WSDL.

Comment: ¿Imposible de responder? ¿por qué? a veces hay guías para cambiar el código desde una librería abandada a una nueva

Comment: Principalmente porque las preguntas deben ser especificas (no genéricas) y las respuestas deben ser acotadas. Tu puedes decir: **"Tengo este código usando la librería X, y tengo este otro código al pasar a la librería Y, en la función Z no se que poner o me tira tal error o no encuentro el reemplazo"**. Eso hace que la pregunta sea especifica a tu problema real (no a cualquier caso del universo) y está acotada a la función Z, porque no es la idea de hacer el trabajo por ti, la idea es prestar una ayuda

Comment: Por otro lado esto te beneficia. Digamos que tu pregunta es valida (que no lo es) y que se pudiera responder como si fuera una guía, solo podría responder alguien con la experiencia en ambas librerías, en cambio si preguntas como te señalo basta que alguien que sepa PHP. Es decir tienes más probabilidades de obtener respuesta. Fíjate que muchas de tus preguntas no tienen respuestas, debes plantearte que quizás no las estas haciendo "respondibles"